# Xcode 4 & Instruments for Memory Leaks

Tags: xcode, instruments

I found useful in some situation to use Instruments for memory leaks. But some times founded memory leaks confuse me.

What in general sense mean that some allocation blocks highlighted ? Ad I assume, leaks always somehow connected with highlighted block ? Or i need to think about leak instrument only as suggest instrument ?

Maybe anybody may point to good article about instruments of session videos?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look Apple's official Instruments [Quick Start Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/InstrumentsQuickStart/InstrumentsQuickStart.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: Edited broken link above. Top level Table of Contents for Instruments is also useful to know about. It's here:  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html